# sort data into deciles based on a rolling subset

Tags: r, sorting, data.table, dplyr, percentile

I am trying to replicate the Fama French 1993 paper using R. I need to do the following sorting :

1. for each month,
2. calculate ME decile breakpoints on NYSE stocks only
3. sort all stocks into the deciles created in 2.

Data generation:

```
    set.seed(1234)
    n = 120
    stocks <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    exchange <- c("NYSE", "NASDAQ", "AMEX")
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Month = 1:12,
                      exchangeCode = exchange[round(runif(n, 1, 3))],
                      Stock = stocks[round(runif(n, 1, 5))],
                      ME=floor(100*abs(rnorm(n)))))
```

Desired Output:

```
ME_NYSE_vals <- as.numeric(paste(df[df$Month==1 & df$exchangeCode=="NYSE","ME"]))

ME_ALL_vals <- as.numeric(paste(df[df$Month==1,"ME"]))

cut(x = ME_ALL_vals,
breaks = c(-Inf,quantile(ME_NYSE_vals,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)),+Inf),
labels = 1:10
)
```

The breaks should be calculated based on ME_NSYE_vals. The cut should be applied to all ME_ALL_vals for each month.

Comment: Add `set.seed`, reduce the data set and add your desired output.

Comment: If you only want NYSE in the resutling data, you can filter before the group_by: `df %>% filter(exchangeCode == "NYSE") %>% group_by(Month) %>% mutate(nTile = ntile(ME, 10))`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question to better reflect what is being sought.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to keep the whole data frame but generate deciles only for the *NYSE* values the code below could do. The point was to generate deciles only for the entries pertaining to the *NYSE* values but to keep the full data set achieving some form of a partial sorting.

```
# Libs
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "magrittr"),
                   character.only = TRUE)
# Transformations
df %<>%
    mutate(nTileNYSE = ifelse(exchangeCode == "NYSE", ntile(ME, 10), NA))
    arrange(nTileNYSE)
```

The code was applied to the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(exchangeCode = c("NYSE", "NASDAQ"), 
                          Stock = c("A", "B", "C", "A"), 
                          Month = 1:12,
                          ME=rnorm(1200)))
```

---

## 2nd approach

Following the discussion in the comments I would suggest the following approach:

```
# Libs --------------------------------------------------------------------

Vectorize(require)(package = c( "tidyr", "dplyr", "magrittr", "xts", "Hmisc"),
                   char = TRUE)

# Data generation ---------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(1234)
n = 120
stocks <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
exchange <- c("NYSE", "NASDAQ", "AMEX")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Month = 1:12,
                          exchangeCode = exchange[round(runif(n, 1, 3))],
                          Stock = stocks[round(runif(n, 1, 5))],
                          ME = floor(100*abs(rnorm(n)))))

# Transformations ---------------------------------------------------------

# For some reason this was needed
df$ME <- as.numeric(as.character(df$ME))

# Generate cuts
dfNtiles <- df %>% 
  arrange(exchangeCode, Month, ME) %>% 
  group_by(exchangeCode, Month) %>% 
  mutate(cutsBsdOnNYSE = cut(x = ME, 
                             breaks = cut2(x = df$ME[df$exchangeCode == "NYSE"],
                                           g = 10, onlycuts = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(cutsBsdOnNYSE) %>% 
  mutate(grpBsdOnNYSE = n())
```

It's fairly straightforward

- Generating cut brackets reflecting subset of the data.
- Applying those brackets to the whole vector *(ME)*
- Numbering the obtained groups so a group identifier is created

  and boils down to:

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question to better reflect what is being sought.

Comment: You could derive cut values using `cut` from `Hmisc` package: `cut2(x = as.numeric(as.character(df$ME[df$exchangeCode == "NYSE"])), g = 10,
     onlycuts = TRUE)`

Comment: thanks! cuts I have, but how do I calculate them AND apply them over all MEs for each month. my "cuts", would do that for a given month, but I can't figure out how to "roll" them over each month... I don't want to resort to looping just yet. there must be a better way...

Comment: sorry, had to update.... thanks! however, the cuts don't roll by month. cutsBsdOnNYSE are calculated using all df$ME[df$exchangeCode == "NYSE"], but this should be done on a monthly basis, i.e. the cuts need to be recalculated each month.